# HTML CSS Table Border not reflecting on row borders

Tags: html, css

I have following HTML code with style...

Below is the table with 5 rows... only table corner is getting bordered not the rows.

**I want the rows as well outlined with same style.**

```
<table width="330" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:1px;border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-collapse: collapse;" >
```

Out put is coming as

[image]

Comment: Like below, use table row <tr> 
Only in old HTML standards setting the border for table gives all cells a border. But that was before css basicaly.
Nowadays it is more logical (by default), a border for the table goes around the table, for the row around the row, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since people seem to be a bit lazy one this one I have created a demo to better explain this.

### HTML:

```
<table width="330" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### CSS:

```
table {
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:black;
    border-style:solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
tr {
    border: 1px solid;
}
td {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/4686t/)

You put the border on `tr` for the rows. If you want the cells you put it on `td`. You should also use `border-collapse:collapse;` on the table. Have a play with it to see what how it works. In short it will collapse the borders into single border (so they don't sit next to each other causing a larger border)

### CSS:

```
td {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/4686t/1/)

---

### Update:

Table with a class:

### CSS:

```
.ruddy {
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:black;
    border-style:solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<table class="ruddy" width="330" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
</table>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/4686t/2/)

Comment: Come on, explain the `-1`. because I said people are lazy and didn't made a simple JSFiddle?

Comment: So you use a `class`. e.g: CSS:`.ruddy { }` HTML: `<table class="ruddy">`

Comment: Again, explain this `-1`. I would love to know what in my answer is worth it a down vote.

Comment: @Ruddy : u seems to become an experts in writing long answers...good job, +1!! :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the style on the `<tr>` tag.

```
<tr style="border:1px solid #000"></tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Read on **[`border-collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse)**.

Specifically, you need `border-collapse: collapse;`

Comment: border-collapse: collapse; is not working; same result

Comment: @logan: I did say **read on border-collapse**. The code is not copy-pastable. Read, understand and implement.

Comment: @logan Read my answer for a little more on it.

Comment: @logan  the answer is given by Daniel Johnson http://stackoverflow.com/a/21330549/2967572

Answer (score 1):

actually border in css for the table will be applicable only on the table not on TR..
because CSS define for the table can not be inherit on TR or TD

if you want to have border on TR then u must define the border property in CSS for the TR element

```
tr
{
   border:1px solid black;
}
```

or for column use the TD instead for TR.

Answer (score 1):

To give borders to **ROWS** you need is another rule:

```
table tr{
    border:1px #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in html

```
<table width="330" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class='table' >
```

in css

```
.table
{
   border:1px solid #000;
}
.table td,.table tr
{
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the style at tr not the table, so it goes like the following:

```
<tr style="border-width:1px;border-color:black;border-style:solid;">
```

But I think it's easier if you use the border attribute. The output is almost similar:

```
<table border="1" width="330" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
```